Specific type of Bar Chart
I would like to create the bar diagram in the image below, as shown in the picture on the left there are equipment designations. In the figure, a bar indicates which time interval there is data in, and its start and end dates on the x-axis. How can you use Excel or Power BI to solve this?


There's an organizational visual called Gantt created by Microsoft. Then load the data in the correct form with the columns "Name, Start Date, End Date", then stacked on a visual. Turn on Group Tasks in Visual Formatting, General, and it organizes the data into the form shown in the image.
